# Keep track if the chosen dropdown option thought the asp.net mvc web app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that allows Projects Management. First the project is chosen from a list, then it can be managed through a number of activities. Currently I’m relying on sessions to keep track of the chosen project id. The problem is that every time the user visits the website, he need to go back to the dashboard and select the project. Is there any alternative solution to using sessions ?

Comment: This question is both too broad and unclear.

Comment: You save data to db when user select option and use everywhere. And when he goes back to dashboard and select another option then you update that row which you save and perform all task. I think this is basic solution but you need to query from db

Comment: @UxmaanAli thank you, That was actually my first choice, but I was looking for an alternative.